# Linked lists in C, ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linked-list

This the error that I get. I'm trying to implement linked lists in c language.

prog.c: In function ‘Insert’: prog.c:33:26: error: ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
struct node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

the code is as below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head;

void Insert(int x);
void Print();

int main(void){

    head = NULL;
    printf("how many numbers?");
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the number");
        sacnf("%d",&x);
        Insert(x);
        Print();
    }

    return 0;
}

void Insert(int x){

    struct node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    (*temp).next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void Print(){

    struct node* temp = head;
    printf("\nThe List is ");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `node`. There is `struct node`. C isn't C++. And [stop casting `malloc` in C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) regardless.

Comment: In C you need to use `typedef` if you want to use a structure name as a type by itself.

Comment: that worked.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in line `struct node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` of function `void Insert(int x)`, it should be `struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`. You can find corrected and working code [Here](http://ideone.com/H7OA1B).

**Note** In line `sacnf("%d",&x);` of function `main(void)`, it should be `scanf("%d",&x);`